# Can one keep their firefox and chrome data on an external hard drive?

Tags: windows, mount, browsing

I want to keep my chrome and firefox browsing data (filled in forms, history, addons, etc) available on a mounted network drive (Windows 10, mounted as Z:\). Is there a way to keep such data on a network mount?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak regarding first-hand experience with Chrome, but Firefox has a very well-known portable version that should be able to do what you want:

[Mozilla Firefox Portable Edition](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to change the default locations of where these browsers store their data, but if all you want is to be able to access the same history etc from multiple devices, you could use their respective Sync functionality.

For example, with Firefox Sync you can synchronise your tabs, bookmarks, passwords, history, preferences, filled forms, add-ons, and the last 25 opened tabs across multiple computers.

Likewise, Chrome sync can sync apps, autofill, bookmarks, extensions, history, passwords, settings, themes, and open tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution if you are looking at a always-connected network drive, is making a symlink from your AppData for that browser and have it pointed at the network drive. Now the files should end up saved to your network drive.

However, I *highly* discourage such uses of networked media, especially for browsers where data is constantly read and written (browser cache, etc). Your best bet would be using the built-in sync features as Monomeeth suggested, but here's this option if you aren't afraid of the possible performance implications.